# I have a finite permutation group and access to a computer algebra system, how can I recognize the structure of the group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, computational-mathematics, gap

I have a fixed permutation group $G$, and cannot tell which finite group it really is in a "human readable" way. I also have GAP.

Is there a step by step computation to give me the structure of this group?

Comment: You could start with $\mathtt{StructureDescription(G)}$. That won't necessarily tell you everything you want to know, but it's certainly the first thing to try.

Comment: See also [7.11: How do I use GAP to "identify" a given group?](http://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html#7.11) from the GAP F.A.Q.

Comment: What do you mean by *which finite group it really is* ? There are over $10^6$ groups of order 1024 alone and most are not obvious products of smaller degree.

Comment: @ahulpke: That's exactly what I am trying to figure out. If I have an integer I can look at its prime factorization and know what it's multiplicative properties are. But what about groups? What is their "prime factorization"?

Comment: I have $G$ as a permutation group (to be specific, I have generators for it) and I want to know how big it is, what subgroups it has, ...

Comment: So you should try $\mathtt{Size(G)}$ or $\mathtt{ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(G)}$.

Comment: There is no "step by step" procedure - you could think of GAP as a "toolbox" where you pick up different tools to analyse different properties of the group and make your reasonings. If you could give a "real-life" example of sone group you're dealing with, the answer exposing a number of such tools could be a useful one.

Comment: @user98246  The closest to a prime factorization would be the composition factors, e.g. using `DisplayCompositionSeries`, but they  don't identify a group uniquely.

Comment: @user98246: if you could give a list of generators for this or another group, someone perhaps would try to provide an example and remove this question from the unanswered queue.

Comment: It would be useful to have this question answered - since the OP haven't replied, perhaps one should just pick up some permutation group and show an example...